# Monitor shows "out of range" message

Tags: ati, resolution, radeon

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and everything was fine until today. I've tried to run a windows game trough wine, the game started but crashed back to the desktop and after that  the screen resolution went to very low. I've got to monitor settings and fixed the resolution to the native 1400x900 and it worked fine until I rebooted my computer. Now instead of the greetings screen (lightdm) all I get is an black screen with the monitor's "out of range" message. How can I fix this ?
I Have a RADEON HD 5800.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to boot into the system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to install my HD 6770 proprietary drivers on Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, Linux Mint 9, 14 and Kubuntu 12.04. I have the same problem as yours.
After installing drivers from different sorces, and rebooting, It shows Out of Range (74.9kHz / 60Hz) , i submitted a question, so far nothing :/

Here is mine:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/244929/monitor-out-of-range-74-9khz-60hz-after-installing-ati-proprietary-drivers